# Read Timeout Exception while deleting 1 million keys

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I have a redis HA with one master and two slaves. And i have around 10 million keys in my redis.
For a given flow i am deleting around 1 Million keys with a batch size of 1000 and simulatneoulsy in other flows keys are getting put into the redis.
but every time while performing delete operation i  encounter java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out. I have kept timeout at 8 seconds.
Is there any issue with Redis Delete?

I am using Jedis client 2.7.

Stack Trace:

```
"redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out":{  
  "RedisInputStream.java:201":"redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.ensureFill",
  "RedisInputStream.java:40":"redis.clients.util.RedisInputStream.readByte",
  "Protocol.java:141":"redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process",
  "Protocol.java:205":"redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read",
  "Connection.java:297":"redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken",
  "Connection.java:267":"redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getAll",
  "Connection.java:259":"redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getAll",
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the redis server is single thread model for process request. So all the command incoming will queued as one by one.

And about DEL operation, It not just remove the key from keyspace, it will also blocks until all the memory for the keys are free. So it slow down your redis server. you could try the UNLINK command.

> This command is very similar to DEL: it removes the specified keys. Just like DEL a key is ignored if it does not exist. However the command performs the actual memory reclaiming in a different thread, so it is not blocking, while DEL is. This is where the command name comes from: the command just unlinks the keys from the keyspace. The actual removal will happen later asynchronously.

EDITED.

Maybe you should try the incrementally deleting and incrementally puting. E.g. Every minute delete 100 keys or 1000 keys.

And if your some key's type is list or set or zset which hold huge data, you might delete it delayed, first collect them, and then delete them when redis is not very busy.

if your put data flow is also this bulk load huge data into redis, incrementally putting.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But we are using 3.0.7 version of Redis. Is there any other way on 3.0.7

Comment: not very sure the whether edited answer could help you.